# Detecting host timeout in rosserial_arduino

Tags: rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you detect on the Arduino's end when the host has stopped responding with rosserial_arduino?

I'd like to implement a safety feature where if the host crashes or otherwise becomes unresponsive, the Arduino will immediately halt any motors. However, nothing in the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino) explains how to access the last read times from the node handle.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254551/detecting-host-timeout-in-rosserial_arduino/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a `connected()` method in the underlying rosserial_client API: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/jade-devel/rosserial_client/src/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h#L286-L288 ; it looks like it does this by monitoring the time sync messages, and the timeout is about 10 seconds.

That's probably a bit too long for a safety timeout, and I'm not aware of any other periodic messages that are built into rosserial.

Probably the best thing to do is to implement your own timeout; my favorite way to do this is to set a timeout on the command message itself. If my firmware doesn't receive a command within 3x the expected command interval, it commands an immediate stop. (I'm not using rosserial, but the principle is the same)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2